# Using React To Create a Loop That Updates A Number Value

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Trying to create an auto-clicker/idle game. So far the entire application works except for this loop. After the loop begins, if I update the counter, different values update in intervals. So my counter will display those different values, going back and forth between them depending on how many times I've tried to mess with the counter while its looping.

I've tried using while loops, if statements, and for loops. And for each of those loops I've tried both `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`. They either lead to the problem above, or the browser crashing.

Here's a video of the issue:
[Youtube Link](https://youtu.be/JomMteAwwvk)

Here's the relevant code I've got currently:

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const [minions, setMinions] = useState(0);
  let minionCost = minions * 10 + 6;

  let autoMinions = () => {
    if (minions > 0) {
      setTimeout(() => {
        setCounter(minions + counter);
      }, 1000);
    } else {
      return null;
    }
  };

  const onClickMinion = () => {
    if (counter < minionCost) {
      console.log(`you don't have ${minionCost} to spend`);
    } else {
      setCounter(counter - minionCost);
      setMinions(minions + 1);
    }
  };
  autoMinions();
};
```

Comment: @khuynh
I tried your idea and the numbers went berserk. I edited my question to add a video of my problem to better show the issue.

Comment: You need to decouple your timer "loop" from your rendering. At the moment every time you render (like each time you click the button) you're starting a new series of timers. (Which is why the numbers went berserk, if wasn't updating every second like you expect, it would be updating x times per second where x is the number of times the component has re-rendered.

Comment: Here's a bad example of it working: https://jsfiddle.net/g7w5qeu3/
I don't have time to show a better version but it would involve keeping track of the next tick time as a date, and dynamically updating the timer (clearing and restarting) on each render to target that next tick time. That would allow you to split the state out into 2 useState calls again too.

Comment: Actually an even better implementation would probably be to keep the game-state separate and have an ability to subscribe to state updates inside the component.

Comment: @david
Ty so much for the help, unfortunately after I implemented what you had as best as I could, this is what happened:
https://youtu.be/hoiDlp7mnIY

Comment: @david the problem was me, I implemented your fix wrong. I went ahead and added the proper functions within setstate.

Comment: the "fix" relies on merging your state into an object, which is probably not ideal. If I were you I'd look into a few state management solutions (something like zustand might work) rather than using ui/component state for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're computing state based off of a previous state, you should use [functional updates](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#functional-updates).

Try passing `setCounter` a function that receives the previous state instead of using `counter` directly (do this with any of your `useState` hooks that depend on previous state):

```js
setCounter(prevCounter => prevCounter + minions)
```

Comment: This is what happened when I tried to apply your idea:
https://youtu.be/dlCCRKd7jHA